# How to run govulncheck with a specific Go version?

Tags: go

I'm trying to scan my Go module for vulnerabilities using the [`govulncheck` tool](https://github.com/golang/vuln). Following the instructions on the ["Managing Go installations" page](https://go.dev/doc/manage-install), I have two Go versions installed: 1.17.9 and 1.18.6:

```
$ go version
go version go1.17.9 linux/amd64
$ go1.18.6 version
go version go1.18.6 linux/amd64
```

My module is built and run with 1.18.6. I installed `govulncheck` using go 1.18.6 using this command:

```
$ go1.18.6 install golang.org/x/vuln/cmd/govulncheck@latest
go: downloading golang.org/x/vuln v0.0.0-20220913170424-c9fe2ba7ccad
go: downloading golang.org/x/mod v0.6.0-dev.0.20220419223038-86c51ed26bb4
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.1.13-0.20220803210227-8b9a1fbdf5c3
go: downloading golang.org/x/exp v0.0.0-20220722155223-a9213eeb770e
```

But when I ran `govulncheck ./...` against my module, it reported issues against Go 1.17.9.

```
$ govulncheck ./...
govulncheck is an experimental tool. Share feedback at https://go.dev/s/govulncheck-feedback.

Scanning for dependencies with known vulnerabilities...
Found 5 known vulnerabilities.

Vulnerability #1: GO-2022-0524
  Calling Reader.Read on an archive containing a large number of
  concatenated 0-length compressed files can cause a panic due to
  stack exhaustion.

  Call stacks in your code:
      path/omitted/example.go:79:67: example.com/example-project/path/omitted/example.Method calls example.com/vulnerable-dependency/path/omitted/example.Foo.Bar, which eventually calls compress/gzip.Reader.Read

  Found in: compress/gzip@go1.17.9
  Fixed in: compress/gzip@go1.18.4
  More info: https://pkg.go.dev/vuln/GO-2022-0524

(etc)
```

The example issue is already fixed in the Go version I'm using (1.18.6), but since `govulncheck` is using 1.17.9 instead of 1.18.6, it's not seeing that the problem is mitigated.

How do I run this tool using my desired Go version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to write my comment as a (slightly more detailed) answer:

According to [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/vuln/cmd/govulncheck), govulncheck will use the `go` command found on the PATH. So one solution would be to export a different PATH (having `go` point to 1.18.6 instead of 1.17.9) only when using govulncheck.

You could do this in your Makefile pretty easily like so:

```
vulncheck: export PATH:=$(PATH_TO_GO_1_18_6):$(PATH)
vulncheck:
     govulncheck ./...
```

Comment: Just to add for future reference. Go itself can have vulnerabilities, so the govulncheck is trying to warn if such vulnerabilities would be triggered in users' code. If the developer builds a Go binary, then the relevant Go version is the one being to build the binary. If the code is being imported by another developer, then the Go version of the importing developer is relevant. Hence, govulncheck checks against the Go version currently used by the developer. For that reason, the version of Go used to build govulncheck should not play a role.

Answer (score 0):

[Install](https://go.dev/doc/manage-install) the specific version you need, for example 1.20.3:

```bash
$ go install golang.org/dl/go1.20.3@latest
$ go1.20.3 download
```

For analyzing source code, [govulncheck](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/vuln/cmd/govulncheck) uses the Go version specified by the “go” command found on the PATH. So you need to prepend the PATH with the bin folder of the newly installed version:

```bash
$ export PATH=$(go1.20.3 env GOROOT)/bin:$PATH
```

Run the govulncheck command as usual:

```bash
$ govulncheck ./...
<...SNIP...>
Using go1.20.3 and govulncheck@v0.0.0 with
<...SNIP...>
```